# How to get Server Sent Events in my Flutter app?

Tags: node.js, json, flutter, dart, server-sent-events

I'm trying to receive SSE data as JSON in my Flutter app. But instead of getting the data I'm getting the following repeated arrays of numbers in my console.

```
    I/flutter (17286): Received streamedResponse.statusCode:200
    I/flutter (17286): Received data:[100, 97, 116, 97, 58, 32, 123, 34, 109, 115, 103, 34, 58, 34, 84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 109, 121, 32, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 34, 125, 10, 10]
    I/flutter (17286): Received data:[100, 97, 116, 97, 58, 32, 123, 34, 109, 115, 103, 34, 58, 34, 84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 109, 121, 32, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 34, 125, 10, 10]
```

Here's what the SSE data looks like on the server

```
data: {"msg":"This is my message"}
data: {"msg":"This is my message"}
data: {"msg":"This is my message"}
    (repeated over and over)
```

And here's the Flutter code;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 http.Client _client;

  MyApp() : super() {
         subscribe();
   }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return MaterialApp(
     title: 'Flutter SSE',
     home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Receive SSE Events'),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Text('Ready for events..'),
    ),
   ),
 );
}

subscribe() async {
  print("Subscribing..");
  try {
   _client = http.Client();

  var request = new http.Request("GET", Uri.parse("http://18.224.97.18:8080/connect"));
  request.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
  request.headers["Accept"] = "text/event-stream";

  Future<http.StreamedResponse> response = _client.send(request);

  response.asStream().listen((streamedResponse) {
    print("Received streamedResponse.statusCode:${streamedResponse.statusCode}");
    streamedResponse.stream.listen((data) {
      print("Received data:$data");
    });

  });
} catch(e) {
  print("Caught $e");
  }
}

 unsubscribe() {
   _client.close();
      }
     }
```

I'm not sure why `"print("Received data:$data")` is giving arrays of numbers instead of the `{"msg":"This is my message"}` in the SSE stream.

Anyone know why I'm getting these numbers instead of the data?

Comment: You are printing the raw bytes received. Use a character codec to get them back to a string, for example `utf8.decode(data)`

Comment: Did you get answer?

Answer (score 1):

[ByteStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/StreamedResponse/stream.html) is the `data` being returned from `streamedResponse.stream.listen()`. To decode the value, you can use `utf8.decode(data)` like what has been mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score -2):

use [flutter_client_sse](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_client_sse)
package for the Server-Sent-Event Stream data. It returns parsed model of the event, id and the data.

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question, it rather gives a differing option